# Can Vue-Router handle clicks from normal anchors rather than router-link?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a scenario where there are two major components on a page; a frame-like component that contains common functionality for many applications (including a bookmark/tab bar) and my actual application code.

Since the frame doesn't actually own the page that it's included on, it seems like it would be incorrect for it to define any routes, however the current page may define their own routes that may match one of those links.  In that case, I'd like `vue-router` to handle those anchor clicks and navigate appropriately rather than doing a full page reload.

Here's a simplified template of what this looks like:

Frame (an external dependency for my app):

```
<Frame>
   <TabStrip>
     <a href="//app1.foo.com/1245"></a>
     <a href="//app2.foo.com/account"></a>
     <a href="//app1.foo.com/2456"></a>
   </TabStrip>
   <slot></slot>
 <Frame>
```

App1:

```
<Frame>
  <App>You're looking at: {{ pageId }}!</App>
</Frame>
```

So when any of the `app1` domain links are clicked from that tab strip, I want my route definitions in `app1` to pick that up rather than it causing a page load.  Since that component is owned by the frame, I don't have access to write `<router-link>` since links to many different apps may co-exist there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Tricky use case. Just to confirm: the TabStrip should change where it navigates based on the component(s) in <slot>?  
Tricky. Can the <slot> components just `$emit` something to communicate to the router? Or, (not that elegant) make several `TabStrip` components, one for each kind of nested component, and then is https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is `is` to programmatically switch the correct one in, based on the slot?
Another possiblity would be using a `vuex` store and based on a variable saved there, programmatically change the router links.

Comment: Out of the suggestions here, your first one was my initial thought when I started trying to do this.  Since I can't use `router-link` in the `TabStrip` for the reasons outlined, I was considering adding a `click` handler to the component that would emit a `navigate` event with the target href which the application could then consume and preventDefault on the original event.  The problem with that approach was I could not find a public API for the Vue router that's "Give me the routes that match this url" in order to impement that

Comment: You could make your own function to do that. You can do 
`const routes this.$router.options.routes.map(x => {
         return {
           name: x.name,
           path: x.path,
           children: x.children
         }
       })` to get all the routes and then repeat the process for each child and "build" a list of all possible routes. Then do the match. Still not a great solution but considering your situation maybe it can work.

Comment: I have different but similar case: I need to put some chunk of html with v-html and this chunk has links which are common anchors. The issue is the same because I need to find a way how to handle those common `a` links inside SPA with router.

I didn't find a way to handle them with vue-router yet. I thought about replacing `a` with `router-link` + use full vue build with Vue.compile function. However it's definitely not the same case as in that question, because in question you can't parse and replace things. I like the idea to handle this with click handler actually.

Comment: I have also stuck at similar situation.... How can we use our existing `<a>` in VueRouter. Anyone got the answer??

Answer (score 0):

Whoo, this is an old one! However, since this question was high in my search results when I was researching this problem, I figured I should answer it.

My use-case was similar to the one in the comments: I needed to capture normal `<a>` links within rendered `v-html` and parse them through the router (the app is rendering Markdown with a light modification that generates internal links in some cases).

Things to note about my solution:

- I'm using Vue3, not Vue2; the biggest difference is that this is the new Vue3 composition-style single page component syntax, but it should be easy to backport to Vue2, if necessary, because the actual things it's doing are standard Vue.
- I stripped out the markdown logic, because it doesn't have anything to do with this question.
- Note the code comment! You will very likely need to design your own conditional logic for how to identify links that need to be routed vs. other links (e.g. if the application in the original question has same-origin links that *aren't* handled by the Vue app, then copy/pasting my solution as-is won't work).

```html
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from "vue-router"

const router = useRouter()

const props = defineProps({
  source: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})

function handleRouteLink(event) {
  const target = event.target
  // IMPORTANT! This is where you need to make a decision that's appropriate
  // for your application. In my case, all links using the same origin are
  // guaranteed to be internal, so I simply use duck-typing for the
  // properties I need and compare the origins. Logic is inverted because I
  // prefer to exit early rather than nest all logic in a conditional (pure
  // style choice; works fine either way, and a non-inverted conditional is
  // arguably easier to read).
  if (!target.pathname || !target.origin || target.origin != window.location.origin) {
    return
  }
  // We've determined this is a link that should be routed, so cancel
  // the event and push it onto the router!
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  router.push(target.pathname)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div v-html="source" @click="handleRouteLink"></div>
</template>
```